# Function that satisfy the properties of the exponential function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $E:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an infinitely continuously differentiable function and $E$ is not zero function 
such that $$E(u+v)=E(u)E(v).$$
Show that $E(x)=e^{ax}$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

My partial answer:

The function $x\mapsto e^{ax}$ satisfies the properties immediately.
For $y=0$, we have $E(x)=E(x)E(0)$. Thus, $E(0)=1$. Let $y\in \mathbb{R}$ is fixed, then 
$$E'(x+y)=E(y)E'(x)$$.

I don't know how to continue the answer. 
Could you give me some hint? 
Thanks.

Comment: $E(x)=0$ also satisfies the condition, doesn't it?

Comment: So far, nothing rules out $E(x) \equiv 0$. With your $E'(x+y) = E(y)E'(x)$, set $x = 0$ and see where that takes you.

Comment: Maybe you can take the $\log$ on both sides of the equation and rewrite it to Cauchy-equation.

Comment: @PeterKošinár We exclude zero function.

Comment: @Ragnar I think that approach should be avoided since log itself is defined by exponential function

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, I understand your clue, though it uses log function. Could we solve it by the approach of Taylor series.

Comment: I didn't think of taking a $\log$. Let $a = E'(0)$ and consider $f(x) = E(x)e^{-ax}$.

Comment: How about E(x) = 1.?

Comment: @DanielFischer how would we know the Taylor's series converges to the function?

Comment: @BettyMock We'd know that only after we saw that $E(x) = e^{ax}$. Seeing that requires only differentiation.

Comment: Right, but all we know to start is E(x) is inf differentiable.

Comment: @StefanSmithn I have edited that we excluded the zero solution

Comment: @tes :     thx.   %%%%

Comment: @BettyMock : if $a=0$ you get $E \equiv 1$.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't quite put it together at the point of my last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on Dan's suggestion we have (d/dx)E(x+y) = E'(x)E(y).  Setting x  = 0 we get E'(y) = E'(0)E(y).  The unique solution of this differential equation is E(y) = $Ce^{ay}$ where a = E'(0).  But if E(0) = 1, C = 1.

The case of E $\equiv$ 1 comes when a = 0; E $\equiv$  0 is from C = 0.

Answer (score 2):

Using the definition of the derivative,

$$E'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{E(x+h)-E(x)}{h} = \ldots 
=\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{E(h)-1}{h} \right)E(x).  $$

By the functional equation, $E(0)=E(0)^2$, so $E(0)=0$ or $1$.  If $E(0)=0$, the functional equation gives $E(x)=0$ for all $x$, and you don't want the zero solution.  So $E(0)=1$.  Therefore 
the last limit exists and is equal to $E'(0)$.   So the derivative of $E$ is proportional to $E$.  $E$ has the form $E(x) = ce^{ax}$ for some constants $c$ and $a$. Again, since $E(0)=1$, $c=1$.

This is how I would do it.  Your work looks valid, but I'm not sure how to progress beyond the last equation you wrote.

I just noticed that this is pretty similar to Daniel Fischer's suggestion, which I think he made before this answer.  If Daniel makes his suggestion an answer, it would not bother me if you accepted it instead of mine.

Comment: @Stephan Smith -- good for you Stephan; I also don't care what solution is accepted.  The main thing is to be helpful; also I want to learn myself.